# Linking error with boost::math and Xcode - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, boost, xcode7

I'm having some trouble linking a boost library to my C++ program in Xcode 7.0.  I am running OSX 10.10.5 and I downloaded Boost 1.59.0.

The error thrown by Xcode is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "boost::math::tools::promote_args::type boost::math::beta(int, int, int)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

After googling for most of the day, I saw that a number of people have had similar issues, but none of the fixes worked for me.

The first thing I tried was from:
http://www.nullptr.me/2014/08/20/boost-with-xcode/

I changed my search paths in Xcode to the appropriate directory and under "Other Linker Flags" I added "-L/usr/local/lib -lboost_math_c99 -lboost_math_tr1".  This gave me the same error.  Curiously, everything ran fine when I copied the exact code from the blogger above (so linking the chrono and system libraries from boost was ok, but as soon as I tried to use a function from math again, it threw the error).

I then saw a number of stackoverflow responses with similar suggestions:

[Boost Xcode C++ command line Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590507/boost-xcode-c-command-line-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

[Using Boost on XCode 5 - Apple LLVM 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888327/using-boost-on-xcode-5-apple-llvm-5-0)

[Linking troubles with boost::program_options on OSX using LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081818/linking-troubles-with-boostprogram-options-on-osx-using-llvm)

These responses seem to suggest that I needed to recompile boost with clang and std11 flags.  I did this with:

> ./bootstrap.sh toolset=clang --with-libraries=math
>
> ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-std=c++11
>    -stdlib=libc++" variant=release linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" link=static stage

and then I put the new libraries where they were expected.  However again when I tried to build in Xcode, I got the exact same error.

For reference, the line that throws the error is:

> double ell = boost::math::beta(2, 2, 1);

At the top I have included:

> boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp
>
> boost/math/tr1.hpp

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  It's hard for me to understand why I can use the chrono and system libraries from boost without trouble, but math throws an error.  I am a statistician and my goal is to speed up an R package, but I need the beta function, which seems to be most easily accessible through boost.  Please let me know if I can provide any more information.