# How to Install Boost Library on Mountain Lion With XCode 5 and iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, boost, markdown

I was trying out Markdown Libraries for iOS and found Bypass - https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass

To run one has to install Boost. I am using Mountain Lion/XCode/iOS 7. I downloaded the version 1_54_0 and tried installing via instructions.

The Problem is './b2 install' is looking for 'local' inside 'usr', which is not present in my system. I have checked.

I have searched at many places but couldn't find a solution for Mountain Lion/XCode 5/iOS 7. I have also tried using the boost.sh script, as some sugested but that too didn't prove fruitful.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How to solve this? Please help.

**Update 1 :**

Xcode Error -

/Users/username/iPhone Projects/Git Hub/bypass/src/parser.h:27:10: 'boost/algorithm/string.hpp' file not found

running boost.sh mentioned in answer here : [How can I compile Boost 1.54.0 (1.54) for the iOS simulator (6.1) on OS X 10.8.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714635/how-can-i-compile-boost-1-54-0-1-54-for-the-ios-simulator-6-1-on-os-x-10-8-4)

`Cleaning everything before we start to build...`

=================================================================
Done

cp: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam-bk: No such file or directory
BOOST_VERSION:     1.54.0
BOOST_LIBS:        random regex graph random chrono thread signals filesystem system date_time
BOOST_SRC:         /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0
IOSBUILDDIR:       /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/build
OSXBUILDDIR:       /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/osx/build
PREFIXDIR:         /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/prefix
IOSFRAMEWORKDIR:   /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/framework
OSXFRAMEWORKDIR:   /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/osx/framework
IPHONE_SDKVERSION: 7.0
XCODE_ROOT:        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
COMPILER:          clang++

=================================================================
Done

Unpacking boost into /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src...
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

=================================================================
Done

./boost.sh: line 171: cd: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0: No such file or directory
Bootstrapping (with libs random,regex,graph,random,chrono,thread,signals,filesystem,system,date_time)
./boost.sh: line 175: ./bootstrap.sh: No such file or directory

=================================================================
Done

Updating boost into /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0...
cp: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 139: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0/tools/build/v2/user-config.jam: No such file or directory

=================================================================
Done

./boost.sh: line 184: cd: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 187: ./bjam: No such file or directory
./boost.sh: line 188: ./bjam: No such file or directory

=================================================================
Done

./boost.sh: line 191: ./bjam: No such file or directory

=================================================================
Done

./boost.sh: line 194: ./b2: No such file or directory

=================================================================
Done

./boost.sh: line 202: cd: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/src/boost_1_54_0: No such file or directory
Splitting all existing fat binaries...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_regex.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_graph.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_graph.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_graph.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_graph.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_graph.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_random.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_chrono.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_signals.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_signals.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_signals.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_signals.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_signals.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_system.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: iphone-build/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a (No such file or directory)
cp: iphonesim-build/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a (No such file or directory)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: can't open input file: osx-build/stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a (No such file or directory)
Decomposing each architecture's .a files
Decomposing libboost_random.a...
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_regex.a...
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_graph.a...
ar: ../libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_graph.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_random.a...
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_random.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_chrono.a...
ar: ../libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_chrono.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_thread.a...
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_thread.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_signals.a...
ar: ../libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_signals.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_filesystem.a...
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_filesystem.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_system.a...
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_system.a: No such file or directory
Decomposing libboost_date_time.a...
ar: ../libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
ar: ../libboost_date_time.a: No such file or directory
Linking each architecture into an uberlib ( libboost_random.a libboost_regex.a libboost_graph.a libboost_random.a libboost_chrono.a libboost_thread.a libboost_signals.a libboost_filesystem.a libboost_system.a libboost_date_time.a => libboost.a )
rm: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/build/*/libboost.a: No such file or directory
...armv6
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...armv7
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...armv7s
ar: obj/*.o: No such file or directory
...i386
./boost.sh: line 252: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin//ar: No such file or directory
rm: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/osx/build/*/libboost.a: No such file or directory
...osx-i386
./boost.sh: line 256: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin//ar: No such file or directory
...x86_64
./boost.sh: line 259: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin//ar: No such file or directory
Framework: Building /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/framework/boost.framework from /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/build...
Framework: Setting up directories...
Framework: Creating symlinks...
Lipoing library into /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/framework/boost.framework/Versions/A/boost...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin//lipo: empty archive with no architecture specification: /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/build/armv6/libboost.a (can't determine architecture for it)

Aborted: Lipo /Users/ajeetkumar/Downloads/ios/framework failed

Comment: Could you copy&paste the errors you get from Boost.Build?

Comment: @IgorR. I have pasted the error logs. Please have a look.

Comment: No /usr/local? Shouldn't that directory be present on your system?

Comment: yes it should. but its not there. I am using 10.9 os x maveric.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my openframeworks addon (which is pre-compiled version of 1.56.0 for iOS) here:
https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost

- Architectures (arm64, armv7, armv7s, i386, x86_64)

Tested and working with Xcode 6 and iOS8

Also script included to build boost yourself using a bash script make.

Comment: Thanks Man! sorry for late reply..i don't have time to test it right now but as soon as i get time..i will test it. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Mac osx 10.10 Yesemite . In `boost.sh` , I just change

```
: ${IPHONE_SDKVERSION:=7.0}
: ${OSX_SDKVERSION:=10.9}
```

To

```
: ${IPHONE_SDKVERSION:=8.0}
: ${OSX_SDKVERSION:=10.10}
```

Then , the issue is gone .

Reference:

1. https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20IOS&referringTitle=Documentation
2. https://gitorious.org/boostoniphone/galbraithjosephs-boostoniphone/source/6ba665dee7e4ad72a32e4e085306baa81420b799:

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing:

`'boost/algorithm/string.hpp' file not found`

You need to install the boost C++ libraries.  Easiest is to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

`homebrew install boost`

Also, in Xcode 7 if you're using Swift and `use_frameworks!` you can't use Bypass as a cocoapod, instead install it as a git submodule using the latest commit from the master branch, then follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass/blob/master/platform/ios/README.md#setup) to get it to compile.

Once you've installed boost remember to add `-I /usr/local/include` to 'Other C Linker Flags' in your target's build settings.  Change that location if you happen to install it elsewhere, but that is where homebrew would install it by default.